# How to change jenkins build folder structure

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have created a freestyle project on Jenkins and configure to build for a github project. The name of the project is `test` and the github name is `my-app`. When I trigger the build I see the content of `my-app` will be cloned to a folder named `test` under jenkins workspace directory. So I want to know how to configure it to clone the git project to be sub-directory under `test`. For example, my current workspace directory is something like: `$JENKINS_HOME/workspace/test/` but I want it to be `$JENKINS_HOME/workspace/test/my-app`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably get in there and mess around with the layouts using a build step that runs a shell (bat or bash)

I'm not sure what that will do though. Jenkins might become confused about the structure.

I'm not sure why changing the folder matters

Comment: I need to create some other script files under the root structure in order to build the job. Isn't there a way to do that?

Comment: I haven't heard of one. Sounds weird, but not "too weird" so it might be possible. It's git though, so, you could rename the source files couldn't you?